# Complex Postgres SQL to RoR ORM

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, orm

Environment: RoR 3.2 + Postgres

I have created a `services` table with 2 text attributes: `title` and `description`

I want to operate the following full text search:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.id) s.*, 
            ts_rank_cd(s.service_tsv, query) AS rank 
        FROM to_tsquery('red | drawing | fun') AS query, 
            services AS s
        WHERE (s.service_tsv @@ query)
        ORDER BY s.id DESC
) AS sub ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

The SQL statement works like a charm, but how do I translate this to the Rails ORM:

```
Service.joins(???).where(???).uniq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Service.find_by_sql(%q{SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.id) s.*, 
            ts_rank_cd(s.service_tsv, query) AS rank 
        FROM to_tsquery('red | drawing | fun') AS query, 
            services AS s
        WHERE (s.service_tsv @@ query)
        ORDER BY s.id DESC
) AS sub ORDER BY rank DESC})
```

Guide here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Comment: Good pick up, I tend to use double quotes and string interpolation for any variable elements.